# The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet-Visual Studio 2019/2022

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, nuget-package

firtst of all I know there is already a post with the same title but none of the solutions provided there helped me. Besides that post is really old and the VS versions are totally different, so I figured that there is something else going on.

I following a tutorial the Getting Started with .NET on AWS tutorial from AWS skill builder and one of the steps is to run the `Updte-Database` command on the ***NuGet*** Package Manager console from Visual Studio.

I've tried this on VS 2022 and VS 2019, but it doesn't work. I keep getting this error:

> Update-Database : The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the
> name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
> the spelling of  the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
> path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Update-Database
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-Database:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

P.S.
The tutorial is Getting Started with .NET on AWS, practice activity, Task 2: Create an Amazon RDS database instance. https://explore.skillbuilder.aws/learn/course/92/play/46160/getting-started-with-net-on-aws;lp=84

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial?

Comment: @John Rotenstein
The tutorial is Getting Started with .NET on AWS, practice activity, Task 2: Create an Amazon RDS database instance.
https://explore.skillbuilder.aws/learn/course/92/play/46160/getting-started-with-net-on-aws;lp=84